# Create new point using distance and angle (ArcGIS)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, point, distance

Using ArcGIS 10.8 or ArcGIS Pro

I have a point shape whose table has 3 columns: PointID, angle, distance. I need a tool that taking that starting point and that distance and that angle, creates another end point at that position.

[image: Like this:]

Comment: `arcpy.PointGeometry.pointFromAngleAndDistance()` does exactly this, though you might need to test if the angle is degrees bearing (clockwise from north) or Cartesian degrees (counterclockwise from east).

Comment: Thanks a lot VINCE!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

**Bearing Distance To Line** is a good option if you have multiple points, it will creates line and then you can convert it to points using **feature vertices to point**.

[image: Bearing Distance To Line]

[image]